# qmail-smtpd TCP file in CentOS with "Parallels Plesk"

Tags: linux, centos, smtp, email

Related to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/70330/local-only-email-with-qmail) questions answer:

I have found the /var/qmail/users/cdb file on my installation, but can't find the qmail-smtpd/tcp file or the tcprules command to create or modify the cdb. I was able to disable relaying on the plesk interface, but still need to deny any incoming mail from external domains with the described ":deny" line. The ones using the combination of CentOS and Plesk: please elaborate on how this works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most installations of qmail put the tcp.smtp files in /etc.  If the file does not exist, then you probably have not installed tcpserver which is installed with the [ucspi package](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp.html).  Was this a pre-installed rpm of qmail, or did you install yourself?  If you installed yourself, installing ucspi was a pre-requisite...
After installing ucspi, you can use the commands below to turn your tcp.smtp file into a cdb file that qmail can read.

```
  tcprules /etc/tcp.smtp.cdb /etc/tcp.smtp.tmp < /etc/tcp.smtp
     chmod 644 /etc/tcp.smtp.cdb
```

You will also need to check that the startup command for qmail-smtpd includes tcpserver, or the tcp filtering will not work.  See these [instructions (life with qmail)](http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#start-qmail) for further help on this, especially section 2.8.2.2.

Another good tool is to create a qmailctl script (see section 2.8.2.1 from life with qmail link above).  This will simplify most qmail management greatly.

Answer (score 1):

I have:

> **/home/vpopmail/etc/tcp.smtp.cdb used on qmail-smptd/run
>   
> -rw-r--r-- 1 vpopmail vchkpw 2288 Dec 26 18:59 tcp.smtp.cdb**
>
> **/etc/tcp.pop3.cdb used in qmail-pop3d/run
>   
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2113 Dec 26 17:26 /etc/tcp.pop3.cdb**

qmail delivery e pop3 run correctly,
but please can you give me the correct user e group for tcp.smtp.cdb and tcp.pop3.cdb?

**My /var/qmail/supervise/qmail-smtpd/run:**

## !/bin/sh

MAXSMTPD=`cat /var/qmail/control/concurrencyincoming`
LOCAL=`head -1 /var/qmail/control/me`

QMAILQUEUE="/var/qmail/bin/simscan"
export QMAILQUEUE

if [ -z "$MAXSMTPD" -o -z "$LOCAL" ]; then
    echo QMAILDUID, NOFILESGID, MAXSMTPD, or LOCAL is unset in
    echo /var/qmail/supervise/qmail-smtpd/run
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f /var/qmail/control/rcpthosts ]; then
    echo "No /var/qmail/control/rcpthosts!"
    echo "Refusing to start SMTP listener because it'll create an open relay"
    exit 1
fi

## exec /usr/local/bin/softlimit -m 2000000 \

```
/usr/local/bin/tcpserver -H -v -x /home/vpopmail/etc/tcp.smtp.cdb -c "$MAXSMTPD" \
-R -u 89 -g 89 0 smtp /usr/local/bin/rblsmtpd -b -C \
-r 'list.dsbl.org:Your message was rejected because the message was sent from a server listed in DSBL - More information regarding this problem is available at http://dsbl.org/listing?%IP% - Please forward this error to your email server support staff for resolution.' \
-r 'sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org:Your message was rejected because the message was sent from a server listed in the Spamhaus RBL - More information regarding this problems is available at http://www.spamhaus.org/query/bl?ip=%IP% - Please forward this error to your email server support staff for resolution.' \
-t 5 /var/qmail/bin/qmail-smtpd 2>&1
```

---

**My /var/qmail/supervise/qmail-pop3d/run:**

> Blockquote
>
> ## !/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/tcpserver \
  -H -v -x /etc/tcp.pop3.cdb \
  -c 30 -R 0 pop3 \
  /var/qmail/bin/qmail-popup mx.myserverdomain.com \
  /home/vpopmail/bin/vchkpw /var/qmail/bin/qmail-pop3d Maildir 2>&1

> Blockquote

regards, Paola